# SQL C# check if exits

Tags: c#, mysql

I have an overview (dataGridView) with all parts (tblpart).

If I want more information for a part I double click the row. For material parts I have another table (tblpart_material) with special material data.

But not all material parts are listes in this table.

How can I check if a partnumber exits in `tblpart_material`?

I tried the following code, but it's not correct

```
SELECT p.number  
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tblpart p
              LEFT JOIN tblpart_material m ON p.number = m.number
              WHERE m.Number = 'MAT100007')
```

And how to put this in my code?

I mean if I have a data it returns an object.

So is the value if it is not existing null? Can I handle this with the following code?

```
public Material GetMaterialByNumber(string Number)
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new MySqlConnection(AppConnection.ConnectionString))
    {
        string query = @" ...";

        if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            db.Open();

        return db.QuerySingle<Material>(q, new { Number });
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What would your expected result be? How is the `Material` class defined?

Comment: Side note: `if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed) db.Open();` is not necessary, you know it's closed so just open it. If you are using Dapper you don't even need that, it will open it for you.

Comment: When "I tried the following code, but it's not correct"  Why do a follow up with "And how to put this in my code?" ?   (Please solve this first problem first.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, put your table in table_name

```
public Material GetMaterialByNumber(string number)
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new MySqlConnection(AppConnection.ConnectionString))
    {
        string query = @"SELECT p1.number FROM table_name p1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tblpart p
              LEFT JOIN tblpart_material m ON p.number = m.number
              WHERE m.Number =  @Number )";

        if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            db.Open();

        return db.QuerySingle<Material>(query, new { Number = number });
    }
}
```

Comment: I still receive the error ```Unknown table 'p' in field list```.

Comment: You need to specify from which table. Sorry I missed that earlier.  SQL  syntax SELECT sth FROM and then clause WHERE